# My application does not access/create my pre-populated database, instead it creates an empty database

Tags: java, android, database, create-table, sqliteopenhelper

I am making a quiz application. I've made a pre-populated database including questionNumber, subject, question, correctAnswer, wrongAnswer1, wrongAnswer2, and wrongAnswer3 as its columns (view the picture at the bottom). I was testing if querying a database will work, so I made a class called TestActivity with its corresponding XML file, "activity_test". I included one button and a textView. My objective is to query the database and show it inside the textView upon clicking the button. My problem is that in my DatabaseHelper class which extends with the SQLiteOpenHelper, creates an empty database instead of querying my pre-populated database. I don't know where I did wrong, but I highly suspect it's the CREATE_TABLE's fault. I might have made typos. I tried retyping and retyping the schema but still no records were shown in the textView.

*In this test, I only tried to query the "wrongAnswers3" column because the database has too many records.*

**This is my "DatabaseAdapter" class**

```
package com.example.quizalarm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAdapter {

    static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="qasadb.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME="qasaMultipleChoicequizdb";
        private static final String QUESTION_NUMBER="questionNumber";
        private static final String SUBJECT="subject";
        private static final String QUESTION="question";
        private static final String CORRECT_ANSWER="correctAnswer";
        private static final String WRONG_ANSWER1="wrongAnswer1";
        private static final String WRONG_ANSWER2="wrongAnswer2";
        private static final String WRONG_ANSWER3="wrongAnswer3";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+
                TABLE_NAME+" ( "+
                QUESTION_NUMBER+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                SUBJECT+" TEXT, "+
                QUESTION+" TEXT, "+
                CORRECT_ANSWER+" TEXT, "+
                WRONG_ANSWER1+" TEXT, " +
                WRONG_ANSWER2+" TEXT, "+
                WRONG_ANSWER3+" TEXT" +
                ")";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private Context context;

        //constructor
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "Constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                Message.message(context, "onCreate was called");
            } catch (SQLException e){
                Message.message(context, ""+e);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrade was called");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    DatabaseHelper helper;
    public DatabaseAdapter (Context context){
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public String getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();

        //select necessary columns from table

        String[] columns={DatabaseHelper.WRONG_ANSWER3};
        Cursor cursor=db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String cWA3 = cursor.getString(6);
            sb.append(cWA3);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**This is my "TestActivity" class**

```
package com.example.quizalarm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseAdapter helper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        helper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    }

    public void viewDetails(View view){
        TextView textShowData = findViewById(R.id.textShowData);
        String data = helper.getData();
        textShowData.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Here's my pre-populated database:
[image: pre-populated database]

the schema of its "qasaMultipleChoicequizdb" table is 
**CREATE TABLE "qasaMultipleChoicequizdb" (
    "questionNumber" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "subject" TEXT,
    "question" TEXT,
    "correctAnswer" TEXT,
    "wrongAnswer1" TEXT,
    "wrongAnswer2" TEXT,
    "wrongAnswer3" TEXT
)**

*My reference to this code is from [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa). Parts/videos 160-166).*

Comment: Are you manually replacing the created database file with the pre-populated one?
Are you also making sure that the version of the pre-populated one is the same as your database version? Note that you are doing a destructive migration in your onUpgrade implementation.

Comment: 1. Should I? if yes then how?
2. how can I know or see what version my pre-populated database is?
3. what is Destructive Migration? I've run my application and clicked the button a lot of times to test it, but I never saw my "onUpgrade was called" toast just the onCreate toast (I view the created database in the device file manager and when it has no records or empty I delete it before running the app again).

Sorry, I'm just new to android app development, I just know some basic terminologies. Please bear with me

Comment: What I mean by destructive migration is that, in your on upgrade method, instead of having a migration that keeps your data, you actually drop the table so anytime there's an upgrade, your data will be deleted. I do not know how to check the version of my app's database, but if the database file was not created with the same version number, your app will either crash or onUpgrade will be called(which deletes the data in your case.

How are you adding elements to you database though?

Comment: I just use DB Browser (SQLite) to populate my database. What I don't understand is how does my application know what database to create? because in the code, I didn't specify the directory of the database file. Does this mean that using a pre-populated database is useless and I need to manually create the elements within the code? or I just need to specify the directory of the pre-populated database? If it's the latter, how can I do it?

Comment: Okay, so I gave up and retried using SQLiteAssetHelper. It worked well and easier to use.

Comment: If you were populating your database with the DB Browser, then you should have downloaded a copy of your app database with the device file explorer, populate it and delete the one in the app and insert the populated one.

Also, your database is created in your app's private data folder on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, It's much easier to use SQLiteAssetHelper than SQLiteOpenHelper. You don't need to use the "CREATE TABLE" schema, You just need to add a certain dependency in the build.gradle (Module: app) to use this.

Here's the link: https://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html.

Hope it helps :)